# How do I check if a variable has gone up?

Tags: python

here is some code. I want to make an if statement but only when a variable has increased

```
while True:
    a += 1

    if a ????               
        print('a has changed')
```

Comment: Make another variable that keeps track of the old value of `a`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option.

```
while True:
    previous = a
    # do stuff
    a += 1

    if a != previous:               
        print('a has changed')
```

Answer (score 1):

A more clever way using the python Observer pattern.

```
class observe_value_change():
   def __init__(self):
      self._initial = 1

   @property
   def position(self):
      return self._initial

   @position.setter
   def position(self, new_value):
      self._initial = new_value
      print("execute more code here!")
      print(self._initial)
```

To test

```
p = observe_value_change()
print(p.position)
p.position = 4
```

Explanation:
When the value of position changes, it will call the position setter method otherwise it will not be called.
So, the if block can be written inside the position setter method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do this:

```
while True:
    old_a = a #Create a variable for the old value of a 
    a += 1

    if a > old_a: #Check the condition if value of a has increased.              
        print('a has changed')
```